# C# Connect database to Visual Studio project

Tags: c#

I have just started studying databases and now I'm trying to connect to a SQL database with Visual Studio. I made the main model. There are tables and stuff. Now I created a console application. I made reference to the project with the data (where the diagram with tables is). But when I try to compile the project I get this error

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(string,
>   params System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some
>   invalid arguments

and this error

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter[]'

And on the other project with the data I get this error

> error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\United\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\C#\EntityFrameworkDemo.Data\EntityFrameworkDemo.Data\bin\Debug\EntityFrameworkDemo.Data.dll'
>   could not be found

I couldn't find a solution to any of the errors. Can you suggest something?

Here is the sample code that I'm trying to run:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EntityFramework;

namespace EntityFramework
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

            foreach (var customer in db.Customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.ContactName);
            }
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We will need to see some code before we can help

Comment: There is no code in the console project

Comment: I assume some code cause this errors on compilation. Exactly that code we want to see.

Comment: Show us the code from the db project, near ExecuteFunction

Comment: I haven't written any code yet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have conflicts between the types defined in the `Sysytem.Data.Entity` assembly and the `EntityFramework` assembly.  If you're using EF 6 or later, remove all references to `System.Data.Entity` and try recompiling.  You may need to remove some lingering `using` statements for those types as well.